# Retrieve rows of a table with only a particular column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as below. I want to pick up those rows which has only 'needs to run' for particular columnA and columnB.In the below example the result should be only the 3rd row.

```
columnA columnB columnC
123     abc     needs to run
123     abc     suceeded
111     abc     needs to run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT columnA,
       columnB,
       columnC
FROM   (
  SELECT columnA,
         columnB,
         columnC,
         SUM(CASE WHEN columnC = 'needs to run' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY columnA, columnB) AS has_other
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  has_other = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try to use the window function with condition aggregate in subquery, then compare the `count` which only `'needs to run'`

```
SELECT t1.columnA,
       t1.columnB,
       t1.columnC
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*,
           COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY columnA,columnB) cnt1,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN columnC = 'needs to run' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY columnA,columnB) cnt2
    FROM T t1 
) t1
WHERE t1.cnt1 = t1.cnt2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT columnA, columnB
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY columnA, columnB
    HAVING count(*) = 1
    ) sub ON table1.columnA = sub.columnA
    AND table1.columnB = sub.columnB
    AND table1.columnC = 'needs to run'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just use `not exists` predicate for same columnA and columnB and any other columnC.

```
select t1.*
  from table1  t1
 where t1.columnc = 'needs to run'
   and not exists ( select null
                      from table1 t2
                     where t1.columna = t2.columna
                       and t1.columnb = t2.columnb
                       and t2.columnc <> 'needs to run'
                  );
```